# Row and column to letter and number excel

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to make a program and I need to be able to transform row and column numbers to Letter of column and number of row in excel.

For example: input: `(0,1)` output: `A1`. Can you help me?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-excel-column-name-given-number/
You can google it like: "number to excel column name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use `chr()`:

```
def convert(tup):
    return f'{chr(tup[0]+65)}{tup[1]}'

print(convert((0, 1)))
```

Output:

```
A1
```

Comment: This will go bust after column Z